# How to encapsulate a file include?

Tags: php, oop, include, encapsulation

If I have a class that includes a file with a constant like so:

```
define("FOO", "bar");
```

Is there a way to make the class include the file with encapsulation so if I use the class somewhere that already has a `FOO` constant defined it won't break?

Comment: What should happen if the constant is already defined? If the constant's name really is this generic, the fact that it is defined doesn't guarantee that it's another version of the same class...

Comment: if your at the stage in your application where you don't know what's defined and what is not then you should rethink your architecture IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a static class and use constants would be the best way to encapsulate specific constants:

```
static class Constants
{
    const Name = 'foo';
    const Path = 'Bar';
}
```

And then use like so:

```
echo Constants::Name; //foo
echo Constants::Path; //bar
```

in regards to the precheck you can do

```
function _defined($key,$check_classes = false)
{
    if($check_classes)
    {
        foreach(get_declared_classes() as $class)
        {
            if(constant($class . '::' . $key) !== null)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    if(!defined($key)) //global Scope
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class a
{
    const bar = 'foo';
}

if(_defined('bar',true)) //This would be true because its within a
{
    //Blah
}
```

---

If your thinking of a situation like so

```
class a
{
    const b = '?';
}
class b
{
    const b = '?';
}
```

the constants are within the class scope so they would have no affect on one another !

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class contant

```
class Foo
{
    constant FOO = 'bar'
}
```

However, you will have to include the class before you can use the constant with `Foo::FOO`. An alternative with regular constants is to use to prefix them with a vendor prefix to make clashes less likely, e.g.

```
define('JOHN_FOO', 'bar')
```

or use the newly introduced namespaces (PHP 5.3)

```
define('JohnIsaacks\FOO', 'bar');
```

But in all cases, I wonder why you would need that. If you want to load classes, simply add in an [autoloader](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php).

Comment: @Robert Sure, but that wouldnt help with contant clashing, just with classes of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if constant already defined using [`defined`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php):

```
<?php
define("FOO", "1");
if (!defined("FOO")) { ## check if constant is not defined yet
    define("FOO", "2");
}
echo FOO;
?>
```